# How to make output of python function stdout format?

Tags: python, stdout

I'm trying to solve a problem where I need to create a function but I need the output to be in stdout format. This is the code i have been working on:

```
def oddNumbers(l, r):
    s = ""
    if l % 2 == 0:
        if r % 2 == 0:
            for i in range(l + 1, r, 2):
                s += str(i) + " "
        else:
            for i in range(l + 1, r + 1, 2):
                s += str(i) + " "
    else:
        if r % 2 == 0:
            for i in range(l, r, 2):
                s += str(i) + " "
        else:
            for i in range(l, r + 1, 2):
                s += str(i) + " "
    return s
```

This code works for single digit outputs but doesn't work for double digit or triple digit answers. How do I get the proper output in stdout format? Any help would be appreciated. thanks!

for example, for oddNumbers(2, 6), I get the ouput:
3
5
which is correct
but for double-digit outputs such as oddNumbers(96, 97), I get the output:
9
7
which is not correct.
i am supposed to get 
97

i don't know how to fix this.

Comment: What do you mean by "stdout format"?

Comment: Do you mean to `print` the returning value to `stdout` instead?

Comment: `' '.join(i for i in range(l, r + 1) if i % 2)`

Comment: Better yet, `' '.join(str(i) for i in range(l if l%2 else l + 1, r+1, 2))`. This only requires one division. (You could even shorten it to `range(l + (not l%2), r+1, 2)`, but readability takes a hit.)

Comment: Wow thank you chepner! your suggestion worked!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean. The code works for all answers.

```
    def oddNumbers(l, r):
    s = ""
    if not l % 2:
        if not r % 2:
            for i in range(l+1, r, 2):
                s += str(i) + " "
        else:
            for i in range(l+1, r+1, 2):
                s += str(i) + " "
    else:
        if not r % 2:
            for i in range(l, r, 2):
                s += str(i) + " "
        else:
            for i in range(l, r+1, 2):
                s += str(i) + " "
    return s

print(oddNumbers(0,10**4))
```

outputs every other number from 1 to 9999